# JavaScript; Counting from 10 to 0 and then again. How to get rid of "undefined" instead of "zero"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a countdown click event. I've managed to do it for counting up to 10.

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let btnForward = document.querySelector(".forward");
let btnBackward = document.querySelector(".backward");
let z = 0;

btnForward.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let numbersPara = document.getElementById("numbersPara");
  z++;
  if (z >= numbers.length) z = 0;
  numbersPara.innerText = numbers[z];
});

// #### Button backwardwork correctly only partially  ######
btnBackward.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let numbersPara = document.getElementById("numbersPara");
  z--;
  if (z < 0) z = 10;
  numbersPara.innerText = numbers[z];
});
```

```html
<div><button class="backward">Backward</button></div>
<div><button class="forward">Forward</button></div>
<div><code id="numbersPara">1</code></div>
```

I want to count up to 10 when I click the button and when it reaches 10 it should switch to 1 again. It works fine.

However, when I started counting down from 10 to 0, it displays "undefined" instead of switching to 10. How to fix it? Anyone knows?

Comment: 10 is beyond the last index of the array it should set it to 9 (`if (z < 0) z = numbers.length - 1;`)

Comment: Thanks, pal. I forgot JS index starts from 0. That makes sense now.

Comment: if (z <= 0) z = numbers.length; --z;

Comment: _"I forgot JS index starts from 0."_ FYI: Almost all programming languages start with 0. I know only Matlab starting with 1.

Comment: QuetinUK - your solution is also working. I checked but can you tell me what --z means.  I'm just a beginner. Does it mean the same as z--?

Comment: Check the difference between preincrement and postincrement. In your code the result is the same but in a different context it behaves differently

Comment: You're right jabaa. QuentinUK's solution detracts 2 everytime I click. I missed that.

Comment: Quentin's suggestion doesn't decrement 2 on its own, it's just that the `--z` is not within the `if` so it runs on every click and combined with your existing `z--` 2 gets subtracted, you would need to remove your exising `z--` to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've made a [classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) [error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) that happens to everyone at some point. In your example, index `0` contains a value of `1`.

To fix this, you just need to change this line (in the `buttonBackward` `click` event listener):

```js
  if (z < 0) z = 10;
```

to the following.

```js
  if (z < 0) z = 9;
```

However, this could be improved further by changing `z = 9` to `z = numbers.length - 1` (better practice in case you want to add or remove elements later):

```js
  if (z < 0) z = numbers.length - 1; // the last index will be numbers.length - 1
```

The full code solution (with some html elements provided to show it working):

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const btnForward = document.querySelector(".forward");
const btnBackward = document.querySelector(".backward");
// set a reference to numbersPara to reduce calls to the DOM
const numbersPara = document.getElementById("numbersPara");
let z = 0;

btnForward.addEventListener("click", () => {
  z++;
  if (z >= numbers.length) z = 0;
  numbersPara.innerText = numbers[z];
});

btnBackward.addEventListener("click", () => {
  z--;
  if (z < 0) z = numbers.length - 1;
  numbersPara.innerText = numbers[z];
});
```

```html
<div><button class="backward">Backward</button></div>
<div><button class="forward">Forward</button></div>
<div><code id="numbersPara">1</code></div>
```